# UIPickerView subclass, toolbar subview not responding to touches?

Tags: uipickerview, subclass, objective-c-2.0

I've created a subclass of UIPickerView. In this subclass I've added a UIToolbar as a subview. The toolbar appears the way I specified in my code, however the done button in the toolbar is not recognizing any touch events.

What am i doing wrong?

**Update:**

The done button is being created like this,

```
UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneButtonPressed:)];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suspect you are not using the right control event for toolbar items (esp if it is segmented control).
use `UIControlEventValueChanged` if you are using `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`. If that is not the case, please post some code to address the issue.

Also, make sure Toolbar is within the frame of your Pickerview for it to respond to the touches, else touches wont reach to ToolBar.

Comment: Is the toolbar within the frame of your custom Pickerview ?

Comment: it's at -44.0 pixels. Like that it sits on top of the picker view

Comment: make sure Toolbar is within the frame of your Pickerview for it to respond to the touches, else touches wont reach to ToolBar.

Comment: Edited the answer, can you please select it now, if it addressed your problem'

Comment: Can you please select the answer , if it addressed your problem.